# Why is paracompactness needed to prove a regular space is normal?

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, separation-axioms, paracompactness

[image]

I am trying to understand why paracompactness is needed to prove a regular space is normal. It was used in the prove above to find a locally finite open refinment $\{w_\lambda\}$ from an open cover. But I fail to understand why we need that. I mean why don't we just set $V=⋃_{x\in B} V_x , U=X| ⋃_{x\in B} C(V_x)$. Why do we need the locally finite open refinment $\{w_\lambda\}$?

Comment: This theorem doesn't say that paracompactness is necessary for a regular space to be normal. It says that paracompactness is **sufficient** for a regular space to be normal.

Comment: @LeeMosher,  but if we can we prove this without the locally finite family (paracompactness) doesn't that mean we can show regular implies normal (which is not true).

Comment: Yes, and that's why you cannot omit the "locally finite family" step in this proof, because otherwise you would be proving something false.

Comment: You want to know where it's *used* in this specific proof, it is not *needed* as such , as @LeeMosher alreeady pointed out.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, obvousily it is needed, otherwise not every regular space is normal.

Comment: Only in the sense that *some condition* is needed. That extra property condition need not be paracompactness. It can be another one too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local finiteness is used in the step where they say $U=X\setminus\bigcup_\gamma\overline{W_\gamma}$ is open since $\bigcup_\gamma \overline{W_\gamma}=\overline{\bigcup W_\gamma}$.  The latter equality is not true for an arbitrary collection of sets $(W_\gamma)$, but it is true for a locally finite collection, since then for any $x\in X$, to test whether $x\in\overline{\bigcup W_\gamma}$ you can restrict to a neighborhood of $x$ which only finitely many $W_\gamma$'s intersect and use the fact that a finite union of closed sets is closed.  So without local finiteness, there is no reason to expect $\bigcup_\gamma\overline{W_\gamma}$ to be closed (after all, it is a possibly *infinite* union of closed sets!), and so there is no reason to expect $U$ to be open.

Comment: But why dont we just define $U$ as $\bigcup_{x\in B} X|C(V_x) $

Comment: Well if you define $U$ that way, why is it open?

Comment: Sorry, I meant $U=X|c(\bigcup_{x\in B}V_x)$. Then $U$ is open.

Comment: Well then how will you prove that $A\subseteq U$?

Comment: because $B\subseteq \bigcup_{x\in B}V_x$ and $A\cap B=\phi$

Comment: How does that imply $A\subseteq U$?

Comment: because in the second part of the proof says that $A\cap c(V_x)=\phi$ .... so the complment of the union of these $V_x$ must contain $A$.

Comment: But you are not taking the complement of their union, you are taking the complement of the *closure* of their union.

Comment: $A\cap c(V_x)=\phi,\forall x\in B\Longrightarrow A\cap \bigcup _{x\in B}c(V_x)=\phi\Longrightarrow A\subseteq U=X\setminus \bigcup _{x\in B}c(V_x)$  Is this right? Now, are you saying that here $U$ is not neccesery open? Why? Isn't $\bigcup _{x\in B}c(V_x)$ closed?

Comment: That is not the definition of $U$ you said you were using.

Comment: And if you are using that definition, then why would $\bigcup_{x\in B}c(V_x)$ be closed?  You've given no reason whatsoever that it should be closed.

Comment: I think I get it now. Because the union of arbitrary collection of closed sets is not necessarly close. Hence we need local finiteness because the finite union of closed sets is closed. Is this right?

Comment: Right, that's exactly what's going on.

Comment: ....Thank you....